# Ellipse transforms into rectangle

Tags: c#, shapes

**When I try to Click yes and Accept the Shape, it is then pushed into the list of Shapes**

[image]

So I need to retain it all so I redraw it (iterating through the shape list/collection using foreach), using this:

```
public void DrawAllShapes(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(Shape shape in _shapes)
        {
            switch (s.type)
            {
                case Shape.ShapeType.rectangle:
                    shape.DrawRectangle(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.points, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.ShapeType.square:
                    shape.DrawSquare(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.points, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.ShapeType.circle:
                    shape.DrawCircle(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.points, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.ShapeType.ellipse:
                    shape.DrawEllipse(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.points, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.ShapeType.triangle:
                    shape.DrawTriangle(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.tPoints.ToArray(), shape.x, shape.y, shape.width, e.Graphics);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

}

This is called in the Canvass painting method.
But this happens. The ellipse is transformed into rectangle.

[image]

**How I add shapes**

```
    public void AcceptShape()
    {
        switch (buttons)
        {
            case Shape.ShapeType.rectangle:
                var rect = new Shape{
                    strokeThickness = strokeRect, 
                    color = rC,
                    points = new Point((int)rX,(int)rY),
                    width = rW,
                    height = rH,
                    type = (Shape.ShapeType)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(Shape.ShapeType), "rectangle")
                };
                draw._shapes.Add(rect);
                Data();
                break;
            case Shape.ShapeType.square:
                var square = new Shape {
                    strokeThickness = strokeSquare,
                    color = sC,
                    points = new Point((int)sX, (int)sY),
                    width = sW,
                    height = sH,
                    type = (Shape.ShapeType)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(Shape.ShapeType), "square")
                };
                draw._shapes.Add(square);
                Data();
                break;
            case Shape.ShapeType.circle:
                var circle= new Shape {
                    strokeThickness = strokeCircle,
                    color = cC,
                    points = new Point((int)cX, (int)cY),
                    width = cW,
                    height = cH,
                    type = (Shape.ShapeType)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(Shape.ShapeType), "circle")
                };
                draw._shapes.Add(circle);
                Data();
                break;
            case Shape.ShapeType.ellipse:
                var ellipse = new Shape {
                    strokeThickness = strokeEllipse,
                    color = eC,
                    points = new Point((int)eX, (int)eY),
                    width = eW,
                    height = eH,
                    type = (Shape.ShapeType)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(Shape.ShapeType), "ellipse")
                };
                draw._shapes.Add(ellipse);
                Data();
                break;
            case Shape.ShapeType.triangle:
                var triangle = new Shape{
                    strokeThickness = strokeTriangle,
                    color = tC,
                    tPoints = t_Points.ToArray(),
                    x=tX,
                    y=tY,
                    width = tW,
                    type = (Shape.ShapeType)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(Shape.ShapeType), "triangle")
                };
                draw._shapes.Add(triangle);
                triangleClicked = false;
                Data();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you get the `type`?

Comment: You could try putting a breakpoint at the line with `switch(shapes)`, and look at the contents of the _shapes collection.  Can you show the code that adds the shape to the _shapes collection?  (Edit your question)

Comment: @kristianp done editing.

Comment: `switch (type)` where does this come from? It's not a property of `Shape`, which leads me to think it's some global variable set based on what new shape you intend to add. You should add a `Type` property to `Shape` and switch on that.

Comment: @John type is public ShapeType type;
        public enum ShapeType
        {
            rectangle, square, circle, ellipse, triangle
        }

Comment: @John it is in the shape class

Comment: @untargeted You're not setting a `Type` value when you create the `Shape` object in your `AcceptShape` method, and if it is indeed part of `Shape` then perhaps you should use `switch (shape.type)` instead of simply `switch (type)` (which is presumably referencing the wrong variable)? Remember: Computers do what you tell them. If you tell them to do the wrong thing, they do the wrong thing.

Comment: oh. I see. Let me try it.

Comment: @John edited the question. Still the same problem

Comment: Dude. What is `switch (s.type)`? What is `s`? You're consistently testing the wrong variable for type. And, my God, what is this abomination?: `type = (Shape.ShapeType)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(Shape.ShapeType), "square")` Why not simply `type = Shape.Shapetype.square` or, better yet `type = buttons` (since, based on your switch statement, buttons is of type `Shape.ShapeType`)?

Comment: See this: `foreach(Shape shape in _shapes)` - your shape variable is `shape`. It's not `s`. It's `shape`. What is `s`? Why are you testing this to try and ascertain the type of `shape`? Does this make any sense to you? If I wanted to find the translation of "to sleep" in Japanese using an English-Japanese dictionary, would I use an English-Spanish dictionary instead? No. Because that wouldn't make any logical sense.

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks. It works now. Calm your nerves. @John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(Shape shape in _shapes)
        {
            switch (shape.type)
            {
                case Shape.ShapeType.rectangle:
                    shape.DrawRectangle(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.points, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.ShapeType.square:
                    shape.DrawSquare(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.points, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.ShapeType.circle:
                    shape.DrawCircle(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.points, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.ShapeType.ellipse:
                    shape.DrawEllipse(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.points, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.ShapeType.triangle:
                    shape.DrawTriangle(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.tPoints.ToArray(), shape.x, shape.y, shape.width, e.Graphics);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Changed the variable to switch.